# WPF Combobox issues

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Just a quick question for you all.

I have two comboboxes, one of which has the data hard coded with:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem/>
</ComboBox>
```

and when I try to use a case statement on SelectionChanged I get from `Convert.ToString(cboForm.SelectedValue): "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Directional Bore"` as a value.

Now on the same form I have another combobox with data that I am populating with `comboboc.items.add()` and the value of that combobox after SelectionChanged is the actual text value.

Is there anything I can do to not have the `"System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: "` in the selected value?

The case statement:

```
string caseSwitch = cboForm.SelectedValue.ToString();
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Directional Bore":
    {
        ReportClass.DirBoreReport("","","");
        cboForm.SelectedIndex = -1;
        //MainAccess.Mw.SpecificForm = false;
        //MainAccess.Mw.frmPage.Height = 4400;
        //MainAccess.Mw.HoldPage = new Uri("DirectionalBore_Combined.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        //if (NavigationService != null) NavigationService.Source = MainAccess.Mw.HoldPage;
        //MainAccess.Mw.SectionBar_DirectionalBore.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //MainAccess.Mw.scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        //MainAccess.Mw.lblForm.Content = "DIRECTIONAL BORE";
        //MainAccess.Mw.Sbar = MainAccess.Mw.SectionBar_DirectionalBore;
        break;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboForm" TabIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,618,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="630" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Height="74" SelectionChanged="cboForm_SelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Directional Bore" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Drain Tile Break" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Fiber Installation" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should override your objects ToString().

Comment: @Sonhja  Tried that, no luck, same thing keeps happening.

Comment: can you show the complete `switch case statement`

Comment: Can you post full code, please?

Comment: Use DisplayMemberPath on XAML and specify the member which you want to show.

Comment: @Sonhja what member would that be with a combobox item?  I included my code for both the xaml and the code behind.

Comment: In this case what I mention it's not useful for you, as you insert the content directly. If you Bind your content to an object/class with members, then you can specify which member of that object/class to show, and then the conversion is authomatic. But in this case you have to do the conversion that @Anand says. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First convert the `SelectedItem` into `ComboBoxItem` and then `ComboBoxItem.Content` will have the string value.

```
        ComboBoxItem item = this.cboForm.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Content.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: just a quick question, how come this works without having to convert it when the combobox is populated from another source?

Comment: When you use `ComboBoxItem` the `ComboBox`s ItemSource is actually a  List<ComboBoxItem>, but when you populate from code behind your are assigning a List<string> to the ItemsSource, hence conversion is not needed in the second case.